# not working while data send by angular js to spring controller and inserting into table by hibernate

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Here I have to send data by  $http.get to spring Controller but the problem is **response is not define** exception is occur

**this my angularJS code**

```
      var app=angular.module('exitApp',['ui.router']);                                                                                                                                                   config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
       //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/resignation');
       $stateProvider
      .state('exit',{
       url:'/exit',
      templateUrl:'resources/js/exit.html',
      controller:'exitCtrl'
      });
      });

     app.controller('exitCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {
     /*$scope.name='';
     $scope.department='';
     $scope.myDate='';
     $scope.designation='';
     $scope.location='';
     $scope.opinion='';
     $scope.performance='';
     $scope.signs='';
     $scope.persuaded='';
     $scope.role='';*/

      $scope.headerText = 'Exit Employee Details..';
    $scope.data=[];

     $scope.submitForm=function(user){
    /*$scope.data.push(user);*/

     var exitdata={
            "name": $scope.name,
            "department":$scope.department,
            "mydate":$scope.myDate,
            "designation":$scope.designation,
            "location":$scope.location,
            "releaving":$scope.releaving,
            "opininon":$scope.opinion,
            "performance":$scope.performance,
            "signs":$scope.signs,
            "persuaded":$scope.persuaded,
            "role":$scope.role
                };

        var exitresponse=$http.get('/hrms/?exit=' +exitdata);
        exitresponse.success(function(user,status,headers,config){
            $scope.data.push(user);

            exitresponse.success(function(){
                alert("Approved! "+ exitdata);
                console.log("msg sent");
            })
        });

          response.error(function(user,status,headers,config){
          alert("Exception details:" + JSON.stringify({user: user}));
          });

          $scope.data.push(user);

          $scope.data=[];

       }
    }]);
```

this is my springController code here i am trying to response the $hhtp.get get data to spring by /exit url:

```
       @RequestMapping(value="/exit",method=RequestMethod.GET)
       @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
       @ResponseBody 
      public String PostService(@RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
      System.out.println(name);

     return "exit";
```

Comment: did the solution help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve your goal with wrong `http` method `GET` instead use `POST`.When you want send whole object we use POST method GET only supports strings appended to the request but not whole object.

Also you are trying to use `.success` for `$http` instead use `.then` which is recommended by Angular as `.success` is deprecated.

Change like below in your JS

```
     app.controller('exitCtrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http) {


          $scope.headerText = 'Exit Employee Details..';
        $scope.data=[];

         $scope.submitForm=function(user){
        /*$scope.data.push(user);*/

         var exitdata={
                "name": $scope.name,
                "department":$scope.department,
                "mydate":$scope.myDate,
                "designation":$scope.designation,
                "location":$scope.location,
                "releaving":$scope.releaving,
                "opininon":$scope.opinion,
                "performance":$scope.performance,
                "signs":$scope.signs,
                "persuaded":$scope.persuaded,
                "role":$scope.role
                    };

        $http.post('/hrms/exit', exitdata).then(function(res) {
                  console.log(res);
                  var user = res.data;
                  $scope.data.push(user);

               }).error(function(res) {

               alert("Exception details:" + res.error);
               });

             $scope.data.push(user);

               $scope.data = [];
        }]);
```

In your controller change from GET to POST

```
//NOTE: ExitData  is model class which you are sending...
@RequestMapping(value="/exit",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json") 

   @ResponseBody 
  public String PostService(@RequestBody ExitData exitdata) {
  System.out.println(exitdata.getName());

 return "exit";
```